# Sbt to publish to both Sonatype and Bintray

Tags: scala, sbt, sonatype, bintray

I have a scala library that I just converted from gradle to sbt.
By default it works by publishing to Sonatype upon release. However I also want to publish it to Bintray. The problem is that Bintray sbt plugin is overwriting the original publish to Sonatype.

I know I can sync to Sonatype and Maven central repository via Bintray. However I still like the way Sonatype handle the validation and check before I really can release it to Maven central.

How do I publish to both Sonatype and Bintray from my release server (not relying on Bintray to sync for me)?

Comment: While using Bintray's Central sync all the validations are still happening on the Sonatype side. Bintray using the OSSRH APIs to trigger the staging and the publishing.

Comment: @JBaruch thank you for your comment. Will I still be able to drop the release from sonatype?

Comment: Once you click the sync button we go all the way, without the additional staging approval step (if I understood your question correctly).

Comment: That's my point, I want to be able to stop it at sonatype staging repo

Comment: You can use Bintray pre-publish as your staging repo and make sure you check that everything looks good there.

Comment: @JBaruch, unfortunately that's more manual process than what I have now. Sonatype does all the automated check if my artifacts are compliance to the Central Maven. Why would I want to do manual check just for the sake of putting my artifact in Bintray?
What I really want is for me to publish my artifacts to both Sonatype and Bintray right from my release process. Once Sonatype does the automated check, I can release my artifacts in Sonatype and then click publish in Bintray.

Comment: I don't understand. If you want to automate everything, you publish to Bintray and sync to Maven Central all using REST APIs. If Sonatype checks fail, you'll get the error from Bintray. If Sonatype checks pass, you'll have the artifacts in Bintray and Central. 
What do I miss?

Comment: If Sonatype checks fails, I'll get error from Bintray. Will my artifacts still be released in Bintray if Sonatype checks failed? I want when Sonatype checks pass, I'll have the artifacts i Bintray and Central, but if Sonatype checks fails I want the artifacts are not released both on Bintray and Central.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and found a setup that works.

sbt-bintray supports a JVM property flag `sbt.sbtbintray`, When it is set to `false`, sbt-bintray will not overwrite the `publishTo` setting (and a few others). So to publish to both sonatype, just run the sbt publish once with the flag set to `true` and once to `false`.

However, I also use the sbt-ci-release plugin, which also overrides the `publishTo` setting (*after* bintray), but does not offer a flag to disable this. To workaround this, copy what sbt-bintray does into your own build:

```
publishTo := {
  val old = publishTo.value
  val p = (publishTo in bintray).value
  if (BintrayPlugin.isEnabledViaProp) p
  else old
}
```

Also see the build:
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-compiler-indices/tree/master/sbt-idea-compiler-indices

Comment: But by running twice your version will be different, right?

Comment: If you use git tags for auto-versioning as in sbt-ci-release, or set the version manually, it will be the same version.

Comment: I'll try in my next release you suggestion. Thank you